# If you were in the middle of sinning but it's prayer time you must still pray?

Tags: salat, fiqh, sin

Suppose you were going to rob a bank and you heard the Adhaan so you stop to pray (it's Fardh) and then rob the bank - the prayer may well be worthless and "hypocritical" but you have obeyed Allah in fulfilling this Fardh act? Comment please?

Answer (score 1):

It is evident from your question that prayer is fardh, so there is no need for further elaboration of the same.

- If a Muslim performs his prayers, the prayers forbids him from sins and wrong-doings. Allah (JJ), says in the holy Quran,

  > Recite [O Muhammad] what has been revealed to you of the Book and establish prayer. Indeed, prayer prohibits immorality and wrongdoing, and the remembrance of Allah is Greater. And Allah knows that which you do.
  >           [Quran 29:45]

Now I am coming towards your question:-

Prayer according to Quran:-

- > Maintain with care the [obligatory] prayers and [in particular] the middle prayer and stand before Allah , devoutly obedient. 
  >   -- al-Baqara 2:238
- > And establish prayer at the two ends of the day and at the approach of the night. Indeed, good deeds do away with misdeeds. That is a reminder for those who remember. -- Hud 11:114

The Hadith of the Prophet PBUH:

- > Adullah ibn Mas‘ood  may  Allah  be  pleased  with  him said, "I asked the Prophet PBUH 'What is the best deed?' He (Prophet PBUH) said: 'Performing prayer in its due time.' I further asked, 'Then what?' He  replied: 'Dutifulness toward parents.' I further asked, 'Then what?' He  replied: 'Performing jihad in the Cause of Allah The Exalted.'" 
  >   [Al-Bukhari and Muslim]

Fardh is an Islamic term which denotes a religious duty commanded by Allah (God) and its denial renders one to come out of the folds of Islam. Now, if somebody omits to perform any Fard without any valid shari'i reason, then such a person becomes a major sinner. So, there is no excuse for omission and missing of fard, whatsoever, anybody can't omit the salah (Fard). If somebody have faith in Allah, then prayers and righteous deeds will not let him to do the sin and evil.

**إِنَّ الصَّلاةَ تَنْهَى عَنِ الْفَحْشَاءِ وَالْمُنْكَرِ**

Comment: But how sincere is the prayer in such a mental state of robbing the bank? Or use another example such as you are about to commit adultery or kill a person, it's prayer time you pray then continue with the sin.

Comment: @user26189 this is a different question which you should ask separately. Note that for praying after committing zina you need to take ghusl ...

Comment: But how sincere is the prayer in such a mental state of robbing the bank or to commit adultery/kill a person? This a separate question.

Answer (score -1):

İt is a little like trying to trick Allah, you pray thinking prayer is what saved you but you rape, kill and steal right after. Yes if you truly believe in Allah prayer will keep you away from sinning, but if you pray yet still do evil then are you not tricking Allah? This question isn't about just prayer, it is about what Allah thinks of sinners. Just an example, you go Infront of Allah; the almighty says you have committed these sins, then you reply saying "but I prayed before committing them and also after committing them". Does anyone really think Allah's justice is so worthless that you can trick him with only prayers?.. prayer is for us to show our appreciation not to save us from hell. First thing Allah demands us is to be good. İf you are evil then why pray? Only answer is that you think you can trick Allah.